# Show changeset # next to filename

Tags: visual-studio-2012, kdiff3

How can I configure VS 2012 to show the changeset number when comparing two changesets?

I have configured Visual Studio 2012 with the following parameters for comparing.

[image]

However I get the below output with this configuration. I would like to see the changeset number that maps to each version of the file.

[image: KDiff3 Screenshot example]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing the arguments to the following will display the changeset number.

```
    %1 --fname %6 %2 --fname %7
```

I found this from [a great msdn archive](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jmanning/archive/2006/02/20/diff-merge-configuration-in-team-foundation-common-command-and-argument-values.aspx) that went into much more detail and covered other diff/merge tools.